# how to perform the bean validation through groovy unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, groovy, spring-webflux

I am trying to perform some parameters validations on the interface which is implements by the controller class.

**interface (generated using swagger)**

```
@Validated
@Tag(name = "PersonService", description = "the person API")
public interface PersonServiceApi {

 @RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/person",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> searchPerson(
    @NotNull @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9-]+") @Size(min = 1, max = 30) @Parameter(name = "name", required = true) @Valid @RequestParam(value = "name", required = true) String name,
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9]+") @Size(min = 0, max = 9) @Parameter(name = "id") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) String id,
    @Min(0) @Parameter(name = "offset") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "offset", required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer offset,
    @Min(1) @Max(30) @Parameter(name = "limit") @Valid @RequestParam(value = "limit", required = false, defaultValue = "30") Integer limit,
    @Parameter(hidden = true) final ServerWebExchange exchange
);
```

}

**Implementation controller:**

```
 @RestController


@Slf4j
public class PesrsonController implements PersonServiceApi {
@Override
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Person>> searchPerson(String name, String id, Integer offset, Integer limit,
                                                                     ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        return this.personService.searchperson(name, id, offset, limit)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(ResponseEntity.noContent().build()));
    }
}
```

**Groovy test:**

```
  @Unroll
        def '"test person name with null "'() {
           
            given: 'service return person details'
            personService.searchperson(name, id, offset, limit) >> Mono.just(new Person())
            when: 'searchpseron by name'
            def response =personControllerTest.searchPerson(name, id, offset, limit).block()
    
            then:
            ConstraintViolationException
    
            where:
    
            name   | id    | offset | limit  |  expectedStatus
            ""     | "750" |   0    |   30   |  HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
```

}

I want to validate @NotNull, I am expecting ConstraintViolationException while passing the empty or null for name.

not sure am following the Groovy test propery or i should follow something with ValidatorFactory? Please guide me here

Answer (score 0):

Interface @Validated should work - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/17000 . Most probably your controller return BadRequest. Please keep in mind that RestControllers throw a `MethodArgumentNotValidException` not `ConstraintViolationException`.

I'm not sure what exactly happened on your case, because response/stacktrace is missing, but my advice here is to debug it.

Easies way for this is to add an `Advicer` and see the exception which is coming:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAdvicer


@ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception) {
    return debug it here!!!
}
```

Comment: In runtime am getting ConstraintViolationException in global exception handler.  But all am looking in the time of unit test.

Comment: most probably you invoke `personControllerTest` which is some kind of stub and will never return and exception but body with status code 400 (BadRequest).

It depends on your Test Configuration for the particular step

Answer (score 0):

```
ReservationManagement object = new ReservationManagement();
Method method = ReservationManagement.class
  .getMethod("createReservation", LocalDate.class, int.class, Customer.class);
Object[] parameterValues = { LocalDate.now(), 0, null };
Set<ConstraintViolation<ReservationManagement>> violations 
  = executableValidator.validateParameters(object, method, parameterValues);
```

https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation-method-constraints#3-programmatic-validation